# In R, how to see max level value in a vector for each year?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm newbie to R programming and as a person who interested in video game culture I wanted to see for each year which game genre has been sold?

Dataframe's name is : vg and my levels of "Genre" column:

```
levels(vg$Genre)
    "Action","Adventure","Fighting", "Misc",
      "Platform" ,  "Puzzle", "Racing", "Role-Playing", 
        "Shooter","Simulation","Sports", "Strategy"
```

and this code shows how many video games has been sold in each year for each level of genre:[image]

```
   table1 <-table(vg$Year,vg$Genre)
```

As I said I want to learn, for each year which type of video games has been sold mostly. From this I can find whether world olympics, wars, crisises effected the sales of related genres. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to get the column names and row names

```
data.frame(Year = row.names(table1), 
        Colnm = colnames(table1)[max.col(table1, 'first')])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I know it is ordered by years but do we have a chance to show it with year values?